# how can make http request in https

Tags: javascript, php, stream, shoutcast, internet-radio

I need run http request in my website with https request.

This code play in my website with http: for example http://mywebsite.com but dont play in https: for example https://mywebsite.com.

```
<audio id="stream" controls preload="none" autoplay style="width: 400px;">
    <source src="http://185.88.177.45:9948/;" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<script>
    var audio = document.getElementById('stream');
    audio.volume = 0.5;
</script>
```

How to play in https webiste?

Comment: as far as I know mixed content is not allowed from an https web page. So that you should really serve the stream through an https host. By the way here's a reference from mozilla about this topic: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content

Comment: have a look at CORS - systems have become quite sensitive to loading stuff NOT on the same host, for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, browser policy dictates that you must use HTTPS for your audio stream if you're using HTTPS for the page.

Older and free builds of SHOUTcast do not support HTTPS.  Icecast does, and can be a drop-in replacement for you.